# Values repeating itself for different sections in a report

Tags: php, object

I am building a exam report module which consists of three sections i.e. section 1 for 1 marks and 10 questions, section 2 for 2 marks and 5 questions and section 3 for 4 marks and 5 questions. Total number of questions are 20 and the total marks are 40. Now when a user finishes exam I am trying to display his result in a report showing section wise report. The issue emerging here is if a user attempts one section only and suppose he has secured 3 correct answers so the report must show 3 in section1 and 0 in other two sections but the report each time is fetching 3 for all the section or we can say all the sections has value of one section. What i need to show is number of "correct answers" 3-0-0 as the user has attempted only one section. Although currently it takes 3 for all the sections.

Here is my code for the frontend,

```
   <tr><td>3</td>

                  <td>Correct Answers</td>

                  <td><?php echo $rep->sectionwiseMockReport($id, $chapterId,1); ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo $rep->sectionwiseMockReport($id, $chapterId,2); ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo $rep->sectionwiseMockReport($id, $chapterId,3); ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo ($rep->sectionwiseMockReport($id, $chapterId,1)+$rep->sectionwiseMockReport($id, $chapterId,2)+$rep->sectionwiseMockReport($id, $chapterId,3)) ; ?></td>

                </tr>
```

And the function that is being called is into a class,

```
function sectionwiseMockReport($userId, $chapterId,$section)

{ 
    $counter1   =   0 ;
    $counter2   =   0 ;
    $counter3   =   0 ;
    $total      =   0 ; 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT question_id, option_id from tbl_result_chapter WHERE user_id = $userId AND chapter_id = $chapterId");     
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if($this->getRightOptionChapter($row['question_id']) == $row['option_id'])
            {
                $section =  $this->idToField("tbl_question_chapter","section",$row['question_id']);
                if($section == 1)
                {
                    $counter1   =   $counter1 + 1 ;
                }
                if($section == 2)
                {
                    $counter2   =   $counter2 + 1 ;
                }
                if($section == 3)

                {

                     $counter3  = $counter3 + 1 ;
                }
            }
        }
            if($section == 1)
                {
                    return $counter1;
                }

                if($section == 2)
                {
                    return $counter2;
                }
                if($section == 3)
                {
                    return $counter3;
                }
}
```

And lastly the function,

```
function getRightOptionChapter($questionId)
{
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tbl_chapter_answer a INNER JOIN tbl_chapter_options o on a.options_id = o.id WHERE a.question_id = $questionId");      
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);      
        return $row['options_id'];
}
```

Any suggestion or help will be a lifesaver. Had been looking for this for couple of days but no success at all.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the issue. The variable `$section` was creating the conflict inside while loop and outside of while loop. Changed the variable name inside the while loop and working swiftly.